# Elastic Search Service on AWS. OR somewhere else

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I've ran into a problem using AWS for hosting an ElasticSearch Instance through their service called "ElasticSearch Service".

I hopefully had this problem fixed, but I almost had to pay $300 this month for using the service an accidentally running multiple ES instances. Stupid me, I didn't read.

So, the idea is to only keep one instance running and at maximum pay a $150 a month.

Now, I'm not a business owner, but I am trying to kick off my own website. Is there no other service out there where I can host an ES service for **cheaper**? $150 a month is a lot when I get 0 return from the business I'm testing out. Or is AWS ElasticSearch Service the only solution? I would like to avoid hosting the service on a local computer.

Any help would be great, I don't know where else to ask this question.

Comment: AWS ES is a managed service and you pay for it. You could always setup your own ES server on an instance. This would be much cheaper, but off course you would have to mange it yourself.

Comment: I know you pay for it. I'm wondering if there are other alternatives. Different pricing models that would be more favorable to someone who is a startup/ small business/ or tinkerer. I know I can manage my own ES server.

Comment: Cheaper alternatives obviously.

Comment: Take a look at Elastic official site, they have its own [cloud service](https://www.elastic.co/cloud/) and you will also get access to all the paid features of the elastic stack, which I don't think you will get at AWS ES without buying an Elastic License.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wow, 300$, and 150$ charges for testing out stuff in AWS a lot.

**[AWS elasticsearch is now offered as part of free-tier](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/01/amazon-elasticsearch-service-free-tier-now-available-on-t2-small-elasticsearch-instances/), under which they are even offering `t2.small.elasticsearch instance` which is even not available in free-tier EC2 instance.**

I've created both t2.small instances and installed my own Elasticsearch in my free-tier account for which I normally pay 20$ a month, as well as **I, 've created AWS Elasticsearch service using `t2.small.elasticsearch instance` which is totally free.**

`t2.small.elasticsearch` can easily satisfy your testing and small size index and moderate traffic. **I would strongly suggest to choose this instance type and create a free-tier account if you don't have one to avoid any charges at all.**

**Tips to avoid cost:**

1. Managing the Elasticsearch isn't big deal(you also mentioned you can manage it) and once your business grow and your AWS Elasticsearch usages crosses more than 20$, you should install your own Elasticsearch on Ec2 instance.
2. You can write lambda function which would automatically stop and start instances, use that to start instances only during traffic hour.
3. Use spot instances to avoid the costly reserved instances and choose the regions which offer cheap pricing(even if it's a bit far from your location).
4. Don't over-provision your Elasticsearch node and just use a single node, which can act as both data and master node to save the cost.
5. Choose cheaper storage option ie instead of costly SSD disks, use a cheap magnetic disk.

Apart from these tips please refer to [this](https://read.acloud.guru/there-are-four-reasons-to-explain-how-using-aws-can-change-the-economic-model-of-the-it-services-850dcc8ea1aa) blog which explains some more concepts in detail **but maybe not very useful if you just follow the above 5 steps specific to reducing the cost of Elasticsearch.**

Comment: Hey fantastic solution. It was a little hard for me to find t2.small.elasticsearch.. doesn't even seem they really like to offer that. Guess that's how they get you. I also changed the storage disc to magnetic as well. Thanks for the help. If I find the cost increasing, yeah hosting on EC2 was the other idea. Yes the other idea is to also use elastic cloud. They offer a cheap option as well for startups.

Comment: To be honest.. I may use Elastic Cloud if I don't run into issues using logstash. But I could see that using an EC2 instance to host ElasticSearch will probably be cheaper in the end.

Comment: @JD333, glad it was helpful, and yeah at the end if you properly use EC2 instance it would be the cheapest one as you know all the managed service also behind the use some bare metal servers only and using your own will give you more flexibility and cost benefits

Comment: Makes sense. I assume that's exactly what Elastic Cloud's is doing interms of hosting elastic search servers.